Audio disconnecting after 5 seconds
I upgraded to dual boot on my pc with windows and linux ubuntu. An issue i have found is that when running ubuntu, my audio seems to disconnect after 5 seconds. I have fairly old speakers so they create a loud buzz when not connected to a device so it gets quite unbearable when it happens. I have tried the sys/module/snd_hda_intel/perameters/power save command but where there is supposedly a 1, there is nothing. And when i try to just type 0 then save abd exit, it comes up with the error "Error writing ys/module/snd_hda_intel/perameters/power_save: No such file or directory" I litterally only installed linux yesterday and am fully a noob when it comes to this so everything i have tried has come from the internet and countless reddit forums so i appologise if this is a super simple fix and i am just being an idiot
